# iconv module issue nodejs

Tags: node.js, iconv

I am struggling to fix this issue, to run node app, I am getting `Error: Cannot find module 'iconv'`, I have tried installed iconv using **npm install iconv** command but getting below error.

```
gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
```

then tried this command - `npm install --g --production windows-build-tools` and got below error

```
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
[                  ] / reify:resolve: timing reifyNode:node_modules/windows-build-tools/node_modules/ajv Completed in 7
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: can you please put the line number where it showing error

Answer (score 0):

So according to what you have provided I am getting to know that this is the problem with the node-gyp in windows so there are some ways to solve it.

1. `npm install –no-optional` use this command
2. Try downloading the `windows-build-tools` package
3. Download the Visual Studio 2015 build tools manually
4. Tell Node to use the 2015 build tools
5. Make sure you have Python 2.7 installed

I think this will help

Comment: Can you please provide me the steps with commands little detailed?

Comment: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2019/03/27/node-gyp-windows/